# Div doesn't hide on-change

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm having a hard time hiding my div. my CampusID div doesnt hide. Any help / suggestion would be greatly appreciated

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Type').change(function() {
    if ($('#type').val() == '1') {
      $('#CampusID').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="input form-control" id="Type" name="Type" required>
  <option value="1">Student</option>
  <option value="2">Employee</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group" id="CampusID">
  <label>Campus</label>
  <select class="input form-control" id="CampusID" name="CampusID">
    <option value="CampusID">---Select Campus---</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont get if why people have to downvote. It's a quesiton. if you can't suggest or give any advice, just go. no need to downvote smh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had one Typo in your code (you selected `$("type")`, but it should have been `$("Type")`) and additionally you closed the `$(document).ready()` twice with `});`

As for the future I would advice you to use `camelCase` for `ID`s instead of `PascalCase`, which is typically used for `class` names in `Javascript`.

```
<select class="input form-control" id="type" name="type" required>
    <option value="1">Student</option>
    <option value="2">Employee</option>
</select>


<div class="form-group" id="CampusID">
    <label>Campus</label>
    <select class="input form-control" id="CampusID" name="CampusID">
        <option value="CampusID">---Select Campus---</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#type').change(function () {
      if ($(this).val() == '1') {
        $('#CampusID').hide();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What typo? Please be more specific in what you have changed to fix the problem as for future users there is not enough context in your answer for them to know exactly which "typo" somewhere in the code you are referring to. - In addition you have decided to change to use `this` instead, with no explanation either why.

Comment: @Nope I have edited my answer with a little bit more explanation. :)

Comment: @MichelEngelen `PascalCase, which is typically used for class names in Javascript` - I'm not sure where this comes from but, aside that there is no official standard for class names the most common forms used are underscores or dashes.

Comment: @Nope I am not taliking about classes from `CSS`, but rather classes which are i.e. used in `React` for `components`

Answer (score 4):

**selectors are case-sensitive**, `type` should be `Type` in `if`

```
if($('#Type').val() == '1') {
```

or even

```
if( $(this).val() == '1') {
```

Answer (score 2):

Typo

```
if($('#type').val() == '1') {
```

should be

```
if($('#Type').val() == '1') {
```